# Screen capturing Android tablet via Mac

Tags: imac, software-recommendation, screen-capture, android, video-capture

I'm working on a project that requires me to screen-capture game play from a game on a Pixel C tablet, but I have an iMac.  I'm wondering if there's a way for me to plug the tablet into the iMac and get the tablet's screen to show up on my iMac screen so I can record the game play footage.

Does anyone know if this is possible?  Or know an alternate way to record the screen from an Android tablet via a Mac?

Answer (score 0):

**From a Mac perspective, this is no different than capturing video from an analog or digital source.**

Depending on the output of the Android Tablet, you can use an  [analog capture device](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/295379/119271)  or a [digital (HDMI/DisplayPort) capture device](http://radnex.us/Elgato_HD60S_Video_Capture).  That interace will allow you to input the video to your Mac.  You'll also need capture software (these devices come with it).  I have used both and currently use the HD60S for capturing output from all sorts of devices like laptops, iPads/iPhones, an XBox (not much) and a DVD/VHS player for trans-coding old movies.

The critical part comes down to your Android tablet and what video adapters it supports.  Basically you need an adapter like the [Lightning to Digital AV Adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/md826am/a/lightning-digital-av-adapter) that allows you to connect an iPad/iPhone to a screen or projector but one made for Android - [an Android to HDMI adapter](https://www.dummies.com/consumer-electronics/smartphones/droid/how-to-connect-an-android-phone-to-an-hdmi-monitor/).  Unfortunately, that's not something I can recommend as Android isn't very much discussed here (and I personally avoid Android like the plague - my experience is limited here).

However, you connect that adapter into the video capture device described above, and you can record game play to your hearts content.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind enabling developer mode in the Android Tablet and [enabling adb debugging](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#Enabling), [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) is a great utility you can install on MacOS to show your Android Tablet display live in a window in MacOS.

Then you can do still screen captures, make video recordings from your Mac screen (using Quicktime, for example), demo something on your Android Tablet to others in a Teams meeting with screen sharing, and so on.